# Dissipation and Impedance

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, impedance, energy, circuit-theory

it is known that power losses (which become heat) in circuits are due to resistances, because of Joule Effect. But sometimes I read that dissipation is due to the real part of a certain impedance, and these two statements are not exactly the same thing.

For instance, let's consider a parallel between a resistance and an inductance:

[image]

Let's evaluate the equivalent impedance of this parallel:

[image]

Now, if the dissipated power is due to the real part of this impedance, there is something that I do not understand. In fact, if R = 0, Re{Z} = 0 so there is no active power, and that's ok.

But we may see that not only R determines the value of Re{Z}: also L, for instance. And how is physically possible that L determines a power loss?

Moreover: how is physically possible that R acts on the reactive power (which is known to be determined by L and/or C...)?

Comment: You have an error at the end of your calculation: \$Z = \frac{\omega^2 L^2 R}{\omega^2 L^2 + R^2} + j\frac{\omega L R^2}{\omega^2 L^2 + R^2}\$.  I just edited: I believe this changes your conclusions.

Comment: _"And how is physically possible that L determines a power loss?"_ in your circuit it doesn't. The power loss is exactly the same whether the inductor is there or not.

Comment: So is it not correct in general to say that real part of an impedance => loss? Only resistance => loss, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your calculation. $$Z = \frac{\omega^2 L^2 R}{\omega^2 L^2 + R^2} + j\frac{\omega L R^2}{\omega^2 L^2 + R^2}$$

The *easy* way to do this is to note that the admittance is easily calculated as $$Y = \frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{j\omega L} = \frac{1}{R}  - j\frac{1}{\omega L}$$

So the current is $$i = Yv = \frac{v}{R} - j\frac{v}{\omega L}$$.

The power is then $$P = i\,v = \frac{v^2}{R} - j\frac{v^2}{\omega L}$$

Note that the real part only depends on the resistance, not the inductance.  You can take your (corrected) value for the impedance and use it to calculate the current, then go through a bunch of gyrations of complex-number algebra to come up with my expression for current, and then come to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

L influences the powerloss as it presents an impedance. Without the inductor 100% of the current would flow through the resistor, without the resistor 100% of the current would flow through the inductor.

The combination however... it is a classic current divider where one limb has an impedance of R and the other has an impedance of \$j\omega L \$

when the supply is DC then the inductor will appear as a short and thus all the current will flow via the inductor and thus no power dissipated in the resistor. At HF the inductor appears as an open-circuit and thus all the current will flow in the resistor

Between DC and HF the current is distributed between the two impedances and thus the ohmic losses vary with frequency and inductance

Comment: Given the source is an ideal voltage source, removing the inductor would not affect power loss at all.

Comment: And an ideal inductor...

Answer (score 1):

> And how is physically possible that L determines a power loss?

As Bruce Abbott said in comments, in your circuit it does not.

But real inductors typically have a loss mechanism that is much better modeled as a **series** resistance than as a parallel resistance as in your circuit.

And real power sources generally have some mechanism that reduces their output voltage as more current as drawn.

If you included either of these effects in your model, you would see the power loss varying when you change the inductor value.

Edit:

In comments you asked,

> how is it possible that reactive components change the dissipated power?

Consider this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHWJwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've chosen the capacitance to give 1 ohm reactance at 1 kHz.

So as drawn, the current delivered to the resistor is \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ {\rm A}\$, and the power consumed by the resistor is \$I^2 R = 0.5\ {\rm W}\$.

If we remove the capacitor (shorting it out), then the current delivered to the resistor is \$1\ \rm A\$, and the power it consumes is 1 W.

The difference between this and your example, is that in your example you have the resistor directly connected across the terminals of an ideal voltage source. In this case, nothing you add in parallel with the resistor (whether it's an inductor, a capacitor, another resistor, or a nonlinear device) will change the power consumed by the resistor, because the voltage applied to it is absolutely fixed by connecting it directly to the ideal voltage source.

In my example, I put the reactive device in series with the resistor so that even though it consumes no power itself, it does change how much voltage ends up across the resistor.

Comment: So is it correct to say that in a circuit with ideal inductors/capacitors, the power loss is the same if they were absent and if there was only the resistance?

Comment: @Kinkya-Byo, no you could easily design a circuit where that's not true.

Comment: So how is it possible that reactive components change the dissipated power?